# Passing data up through nested Components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Prefacing this with a thought; I think I might require a recursive component but that's beyond my current ability with native js and React so I feel like I have Swiss cheese understanding of React at this point.

**The problem**:

I have an array of `metafields` containing `metafield` objects with the following structure:

```
{
  metafields: [
    { 0: 
      { namespace: "namespaceVal", 
        key: "keyVal", 
        val: [
          0: "val1", 
          1: "val2", 
          2: "val3" 
        ]
      }
    }, 
    ...
  ]
}
```

My code maps `metafields` into Cards and within each card lives a component `<MetafieldInput metafields={metafields['value']} />` and within that component the value array gets mapped to input fields. Overall it looks like:

```
// App
render() {
  const metafields = this.state.metafields;
  return (
    {metafields.map(metafield) => (
      <MetafieldInputs metafields={metafield['value']} />
    )}
  )
}

//MetafieldInputs
this.state = { metafields: this.props.metafields}

render() {
  const metafields = this.state;
  return (
    {metafields.map((meta, i) => (
      <TextField 
        value={meta}
        changeKey={meta}
        onChange={(val) => {
          this.setState(prevState => {
            return { metafields: prevState.metafields.map((field, j) => {
              if(j === i) { field = val; }
              return field;
            })};
          });
        }}
      />
    ))}
  )
}
```

Up to this point everything *displays* correctly and I can change the inputs! However the change happens one at a time, as in I hit a key then I have to click back into the input to add another character. It seems like everything gets re-rendered which is why I have to click back into the input to make another change.

Am I able to use components in this way? It feels like I'm working my way into nesting components but everything I've read says not to nest components. Am I overcomplicating this issue? The only solution I have is to rip out the React portion and take it to pure javascript.

guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try adding a `key` prop to each input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that to out source the onChange handler, and the code can be understood a little bit more easier.

Mainly React does not update state right after `setState()` is called, it does a batch job. Therefore it can happen that several `setState` calls are accessing one reference point. If you directly mutate the state, it can cause chaos as other state can use the updated state while doing the batch job.

Also, if you out source onChange handler in the App level, you can change MetafieldInputs into a functional component rather than a class-bases component. Functional based component costs less than class based component and can boost the performance.

Below are updated code, tested. I assume you use Material UI's TextField, but onChangeHandler should also work in your own component.

```js
// Full App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MetafieldInputs from './MetafieldInputs';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        metafields: [
            {
                metafield:
                {
                    namespace: "namespaceVal",
                    key: "keyVal",
                    val: [
                        { '0': "val1" },
                        { '1': "val2" },
                        { '2': "val3" }
                    ]
                }
            },
        ]
    }

    // will never be triggered as from React point of view, the state never changes
    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log('componentDidUpdate')
    }

    render() {
        const metafields = this.state.metafields;
        const metafieldsKeys = Object.keys(metafields);
        const renderInputs = metafieldsKeys.map(key => {
            const metafield = metafields[key];
            return <MetafieldInputs metafields={metafield.metafield.val} key={metafield.metafield.key} />;
        })
        return (
            <div>
                {renderInputs}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;

// full MetafieldInputs
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

class MetafieldInputs extends Component {
    state = {
        metafields: this.props.metafields
    }

    onChangeHandler = (e, index) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const updateMetafields = [...prevState.metafields];
            const updatedFields = { ...updateMetafields[index] }
            updatedFields[index] = value
            updateMetafields[index] = updatedFields;
            return { metafields: updateMetafields }
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { metafields } = this.state;
        // will always remain the same
        console.log('this.props', this.props)
        return (
            <div>
                {metafields.map((meta, i) => {
                    return (
                        <TextField
                            value={meta[i]}
                            changekey={meta}
                            onChange={(e) => this.onChangeHandler(e, i)}
                            // generally it is not a good idea to use index as a key.
                            key={i}
                        />
                    )
                }
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MetafieldInputs
```

Again, IF you out source the `onChangeHandler` to `App` class, `MetafieldInputs` can be a pure functional component, and all the state management can be done in the `App` class.

On the other hand, if you want to keep a pure and clean `App` class, you can also store metafields into MetafieldInputs class in case you might need some other logic in your application.

For instance, your application renders more components than the example does, and MetafieldInputs should not be rendered until something happened. If you fetch data from server end, it is better to fetch the data when it is needed rather than fetching all the data in the App component.

Comment: Once I moved the onChange handler to the App and passed it to the MetafieldsInput child my changes were no longer registering. When I try to assign `const value = e.target.value` I get an undefined error.

Comment: You might want to double check if your state management is correct as the objects are nested.

Comment: I was able to get it working but it acts as my code had with only one input being accepted before rendering again so I have to click back into the input field. Is this where moving the onChange handler into the App would come into play and prevent that?

Comment: Checkout here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/783. "I solved it for my case, you need to provide an unique id to that text field.", I also tried it and then the input field does not lose focus again. I also updated the code, you can try it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance on this, I was able to get it working but it leaves me with one final question related to this. I'm able to change each input and set the state of the MetafieldsInput but a have a onSave handler in the App that doesn't see these new changes. Is this why one would bind the onChange within the parent app and not the component?

Comment: React supports one way binding not two ways binding, so the update in the child component does not change the state of the parent component. What you can do is either move your onChangeHandler to the App level, or move the whole metafields state to MetafieldInputs level. I also updated the code, you can check the console to see if lifecycle method(componentDidUpdate) has been triggered. You can also check the official website for more lifecycle methods, those are very important concepts to React application.

Comment: When I move the onChangeHandler to the App it doesn't seem to have a way to identify which `value` on which `metafield` to update. By logging the value and index of the changes I get the original value + the character key I pressed and the index is the PolarisTextField#. I cannot use prevState on metafields here because it returns undefined.

Comment: You are using a nested object here, and for the objects in `metafields`, they are key-value pair. For instance, `metafields['0']` will gives you `namespace`, `key`, `val` etc, you have to make sure which objects in the `metafields` you are referencing. Try to use debugger or add some more console.log, and you can easily identify if you have referenced wrong objects or you have not yet successfully referenced the object you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the onChange at the app level. You should just pass the onChange function into MetaFieldsInput and always use `this.props.metafields` when rendering

Comment: Once I moved the onChange function into the app level and passed it to the child my changes are no longer getting registered.